# "Try Ubuntu without installing" appears on one computer, not on another

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb

I am trying to run Ubuntu 12.04.05 via USB. It shows the option to run via USB on one of my computers, but not the other 2. How can I get it to display on these other computers?

1) On my oldest computer (32 bit Intel), it shows the following screen which is fine:

[image]

2) On my 2 newer computers (which are both barebones / nuc computers, one is 64 bit Intel, another is AMD 32 bit) I get the following GRUB screen which doesn't offer the option to run from USB:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to know why it is behaving like this is to go thru the source code of Ubuntu 12.04.05. Ubuntu is open source and you can go thru it. Essentially the kernel modules which are interacting with H/W and to some extend of the installer routines. Any time installers are running they probe the underlying hardware and based on that they behave. Your old computer may be having USB 2.0 interface only plus a lot of stuff(in terms of old hardware) which makes the installer make a decision how to behave. Please specify full details of all the H/W configuration and the screen shots to logically find out why it is doing something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While I like reading code, I'm not confident enough to reason about kernel source code!